# Full browser width responsive background image with fixed height

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

I know this type of question has been asked a million times, and seemingly there are tons of duplicates, but I have not been able to find documentation on or figure out how to very specifically:

1. Make the image 100% width of the browser window.
2. Make the image a background image.
3. Make the image responsive.
4. Make the image have an adjustable fixed height. ( meaning I can make it `500px` tall or `800px` tall and it retains its aspect ratio and full browser width )

Is this possible to do with pure css or is jquery or javascript required?

I am open to bootstrap techniques as well.

Currently I have this technique but it's limiting in that I can't really define the height and the image gets cropped when I put content inside.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page-section">
    <?php if( get_field('landing_hero_image') ): ?>
        <div class="hero-img-wrap">
            <div class="landing-hero" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('landing_hero_image'); ?>);">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.page-section {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
.landing-hero {
    padding: 22% 0 20% 0;
    margin:auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
    -moz-background-size: cover!important;
    background-size: cover!important;
    -o-background-size: cover!important;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling the background image dynamically? Is there a reason that you can't set `background-image` along with the other CSS properties?

Comment: @TheAcolyte I am using advanced custom fields in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can achieve what you want only with CSS . Links to help you out:

[Responsive Images and Background Images](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp)

[Keeping aspect ratio at all times](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/)

I will post one more link as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by adding the `cover` property to the `body` and then defining the desired height within the actual div using padding.

**CSS**

```
.landing-hero {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    padding-bottom: 42%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
body {
    font:300 11px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#444;
    height: 100%; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<?php if( get_field('landing_hero_image') ): ?>
    <div class="landing-hero" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('landing_hero_image'); ?>);">
    </div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```